# How to get the First and Last record

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

again. Im traying to control a set of data that have to begin with a 22 CodeId (GO) and finish with a 23 CodeId (STOP). Sometimes the data can come like the example. So, I have to check the first record to see if is CodeId = 23 then delete this record, and with the last record if CodeId = 22 Then delete the record. The timedate var is ordered.

```
DATE                DriverId CodeId
**2014/03/01 13:50:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP**
2014/03/01 14:00:00, 7168,     22     -- GO
2014/03/01 14:30:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP
2014/03/01 14:40:00, 7168,     22     -- GO
2014/03/01 16:10:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP
2014/03/01 16:50:00, 7168,     22     -- GO
2014/03/01 17:20:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP
2014/03/01 18:30:00, 7168,     22     -- GO
2014/03/01 19:10:00, 7168,     23     -- STOP
**2014/03/01 19:20:00, 7168,     22     -- GO**
```

I wrote this code

```
IF (SELECT TOP(1) CodeId FROM #tbl) = 23
BEGIN
   DELETE ... (Dont know what to do)
END

IF (SELECT TOP(1) CodeId FROM #tbl ORDER BY DATE DESC) = 22
BEGIN
   DELETE ... (Dont know what to do)
END
```

I dont know the DELETE statement, can you help me please? If you consider that I have to solve this problem in a different way please let me know how. Thank you in advance.

Im using MS SQL server 2012

Comment: What defines the First and Last record in a data set? In your given sample data the first record has the smallest datetime value which is understandable. but what about last record? how you pick that record to be the last record?

Comment: Im sorry, there was a mistake. The datetime var is ORDER BY ASC

Comment: No, unless there's an explicit `ORDER BY`, statement results have no guaranteed order.  The rows in a table have no inherent order (usual results from use of an clustered index notwithstanding).  Just because you're getting results in the order you expect doesn't mean they always will be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;With CTE
AS (
    SELECT [DATE],DriverId, CodeId,
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] ASC) rn_Stop
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) rn_Go
    FROM Table_Name
   )
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE 
      (rn_Stop = 1 AND CodeId = 23)
OR  
      (rn_Go   = 1 AND CodeId = 22)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you :

```
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','cur_test')=1
        CLOSE cur_test

    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','cur_test')=-1
        DEALLOCATE cur_test;

    DECLARE  @v_DriverId INT
            ,@v_CodeId INT

    DECLARE cur_test CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DriverId, CodeId
    FROM #tbl 
    ORDER BY DATE DESC



    OPEN cur_test   
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_test INTO @v_DriverId, @v_CodeId
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   

            IF (@v_CodeId = 22)
            BEGIN
                --GO....Do this ...Do that...@v_DriverId
            END


            IF (@v_CodeId = 23)
            BEGIN
                --STOP....Do this ...Do that...@v_DriverId
            END


        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_test INTO @v_DriverId, @v_CodeId
    END   

    CLOSE cur_test   
    DEALLOCATE cur_test
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you DAOUI for answer. I used M,Ali code and works fine for me. I will try your code too, so I can learn another way. Thank you again.